# Extracting book title and author from website - Python 3

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to create two Python lists - one of book titles, and one of the books' authors, from a publisher's "coming soon" website.

I have tried a similar approach on other publisher's sites with success, but on this site it does not seem to be working. I am new to parsing html so I am obviously missing something, just can't figure out what. The find_all function just returns an empty list, so my titles and authors lists are empty too.

For reference, this is what the html shows when I click "inspect" in my browser for the first title and author, respectively. I've looked through the BS4 documentation and still can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

```
<h3 class="sp__the-title"><a href="/books/9781250182937">Flame</a></h3>


<p class="sp__the-author">Donna Grant</p>
```

Thanks for your help!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = 'https://us.macmillan.com/search?collection=coming-soon'
page_response = requests.get(page) 
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_response.content, "html.parser") 

titles = []
for tag in soup.find_all("h3", {"class":"sp__the-title"}):
    print(tag.text)
    titles.append(tag.text)

authors = []   
for tag in soup.find_all("p", {"class":"sp__the-author"}):
    print(tag.text)
    authors.append(tag.text)
```

Comment: I just run your code and its working fine on me. The lists are not empty.

Comment: Interesting - can you show me what the output looks like? I'm glad it's working for somebody!

Comment: ```authors = ['Donna Grant', 'Ken Ishikawa, Eiichi Shimizu, Tomohiro Shimoguchi......etc] , titles = ['Flame', 'Getter Robo Devolution Vol. 5', 'Bring Up the Bodies',...etc]```. Try to see cookies and headers. Maybe this cause the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "try to see cookies and headers"? That output is exactly what I need - so my code is the exact code you're running then? Thanks for your help!

Comment: So today it seems to be working perfectly - I guess I need to look into how to use the requests browser - you're right, the website seems to not like it depending on the time of day and how frequently I am running  it. But the code itself works - thanks for verifying!